# I can not "POST" to server PHP from android

Tags: php, android, http, post

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddNewProduct.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
        {

            String nameproducts = inputName.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameproducts));
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(http://localhost:8080/Ten_project/create_product.php);
            try {

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                finish();
                result.setText("success"); 

            }
         catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
             e.printStackTrace();
            } 
         catch (IOException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

         return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute()
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

/////////// PHP code
/database.php

```
class database{
    var $_dbh = '';
    var $_sql = '';
    var $_cursor = NULL;        

    public function database() {
        $this->_dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=thu_nghiem','root','');
        $this->_dbh->query('set names "utf8"');
    }

    public function setQuery($sql) {
        $this->_sql = $sql;
    }

    //Function execute the query 
    public function execute($options=array()) {

            $this->_cursor = $this->_dbh->prepare($this->_sql);

        $bien =     $this->_cursor->execute($options);
        echo 'Lop database <br/>';
        var_dump($bien);
        echo '<br/>';
        var_dump($this->_cursor);

            return $this->_cursor;
    }

    //Function load datas on table
    public function loadAllRows($options=array()) {
        if(!$options) {
            if(!$result = $this->execute())
                return false;
        }
        else {
            if(!$result = $this->execute($options))
                return false;
        }
        return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    //Function load 1 data on the table
    public function loadRow($option=array()) {
        if(!$option) {
            if(!$result = $this->execute())
                return false;
        }
        else {
            if(!$result = $this->execute($option))
                return false;
        }
        return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    //Function count the record on the table
    public function loadRecord($option=array()) {
        if(!$option) {
            if(!$result = $this->execute())
                return false;
        }
        else {
            if(!$result = $this->execute($option))
                return false;
        }
        return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }

    public function getLastId() {
        return $this->_dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        $this->_dbh = NULL;
    }

}
```

create_product.php

```
if (isset($_POST['nameproducts'])) {

$name = $_POST['nameproducts'];

require_once('database.php');

$chuoi_sql = "INSERT INTO products(name) VALUES('$name')";
$pdo->setQuery($chuoi_sql) ;
$result = $pdo->execute(array('$name'));

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve: Make a simple POST request from Android application to Apache web-server running on my development PC and display the POSTed data from PHP script to which the form is sent.
So, why i can't "POST" to server, i use warpserver. Error in server or in my android client ?
why `HTTPCLIENT.execute()` can't run.

Comment: what log you are getting can u post here..

Comment: Are you getting any error?Could you post your logcat stacktrace here so that we can see where exactly you're having problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 24 of `CreateNewProduct`,

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(http://localhost:8080/Ten_project/create_product.php);
```

As you're passing your url as a string, you need to wrap your url inside double quotes.

Secondly, `localhost` won't work in your android emulator.You need to use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`.So you should use

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/Ten_project/create_product.php");
```

In your logcat, you will see `IllegalArgumentException` if you have set an invalid uri.

Note : If `10.0.2.2` doesn't work for you, you can always use your local ip.Just don't use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Oh one more question, Sr i'm a newbie android programmer. So, my apps have bug : ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker. How can i fix this ?

Comment: If you have more problems, please start a new question and i will be happy to help you there.These errors can't be rectified like this without seeing your proper code and stacktrace.Or you can edit your question here explaining your problem with stacktrace and i will edit my answer too according to your need.